# Foreign key issues with multiple relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I've been trying to figure out how I should be laying the relations between these two models code first. I need two relations to be made:

1. One to one: A branch should have a contactperson but a user is not always a contactperson. To specify this relation a branch has a ContactPersonId and ContactPerson referring to the Id of a User.
2. One to many User can be linked to a branch but doesn't have to be. Branches can have zero to many users linked to them. To specify this relation I have a optional BranchId in User and a ICollection of users in Branch

Now is my issue that I get foreign key restrains when I'm creating a new branch even tho the contact person does exist in the database.

```
public class Branch
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid()!;
    public string BranchName { get; set; } = default!;
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public Guid? ContactPersonId { get; set; } = default!;
    public User? ContactPerson { get; set; } = default!;

    public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    
    [ForeignKey("BranchId")]
    public ICollection<User>? Users { get; set;  } = new List<User>();

}
```

User Class

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid()!;
    public string FullName { get; set; } = default!;
    public string Email { get; set; } = default!;
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = default!;
    public string? Password { get; set; }
    public string? Salt { get; set; }
    public UserRoles Role { get; set; }
    public Guid? BranchId { get; set; }
}
```

**Update**

I resolved it differently, Instead of the annotations I added the following to the dbcontext, It could probably be done with the annotations but this is a lot more clear to me personally.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Branch>()
            .HasOne<User>(s => s.ContactPerson)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Branch>(s => s.ContactPersonId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Branch>()
            .HasMany<User>(s => s.Users)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey("BranchId");
    }
```

Comment: The `[ForeignKey("BranchId")]` should be placed above the `BranchId`-Property of the user not the `Users` of the branch. Also how did you specify the relation type of branches and users (one to many, one to one, etc.)?

Comment: @MrCodingB I adjusted the question, I hope this is what you meant with the specification. I did move the foreign key what seems to work but for some reason I get a ContactPersonId1 on the branch table

Comment: ContactPersonId1 might be created due to the ContactPerson property. Since that might automatically be linked to a `User` another Id-field will be created for it. So for this relation, only the `ContactPerson`-Property would suffice and you could remove the `ContactPersonId`-Property along with the foreign key attribute.

Comment: @MrCodingB You are right, however I wanted to include the ContactPerson object to my response. I just updated the question with my final solution to get this done. Thanks for your help!